# Stylesheet does not load despite functions.php

Tags: functions, css, wp-enqueue-style

I am calling my stylesheet `styles.css` within `functions.php`. Also adding `add_action`. But it does not work…

```
<?php
function myBlog_files() {
wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myBlog_files');
?>
```

`styles.css` is on the same level as `functions.php` in directory.
Do I need to call the function within `index.php` or elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: It’s style.css, singular.

Comment: I called it styles.css

Comment: Which is why it isn't working. It needs to be style.css.

Comment: @S.H if you want to use `get_stylesheet_uri` it **must** be `style.css`, a `style.css` is a mandatory file in a WP theme anyway. If you want to enqueue a file other than `style.css` you need to specify it, WP isn't psychic and needs to be told explicitly

Comment: I did not had a header.php – only an index.php. After including it and "singularized" the stylesheet it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> - You can used to below snippet code for enqueue your css

```
<?php
function myBlog_files() {
wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_template_directory_uri()./style.css);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myBlog_files');
?>
```

> - Add Your custom-style.css in another folder you add in folder name in before custom-style.css

For Example :

```
wp_enqueue_style('styles', get_template_directory_uri()./folder name/style.css);
```

[Refer link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) for more knowledge